# What is neuronal computation?

Tags: computational-model

Can someone give me a good explanation of what is neuronal computation and some examples of its use in neuroscience investigation?

Comment: Hi Welcome to Bio.SE! What research have you done on your own? we [ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that all question askers provide evidence that they've tried to answer their own question. [Piccinini & Bahar (2013)](http://www.umsl.edu/~piccininig/Neural_Computation_and_the_Computational_Theory_of_Cognition.pdf) seems like an ok start to get you some citations to explore...

Answer (score 1):

The term *neural computation* is basically synonymous with *[computational neuroscience.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_neuroscience)*  It is the science of studying how the brain processes information by creating realistic mathematical models. Unlike general study of *artificial neural networks* (ANNs), neural computation heavily relies on biological accurateness. However, it may use models from ANN research, and vice versa.

Also see this course description of the [PhD level course](http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~tai/nc11.html) "Neural Computation" at Carnegie Mellon University  (CMU) :

> Neural Computation is an area of interdisciplinary study that seeks to
>   understand how the brain computes to achieve natural intelligence. **It
>   seeks to understand the computational principles and mechanisms of
>   intelligent behaviors and mental abilities** -- such as perception,
>   language, motor control, and learning -- by building artificial
>   systems and computational models with the same capabilities. This
>   course explores how neurons encode and process information, adapt and
>   learn, communicate and compute at the individual level as well as at
>   the levels of networks and systems. It will cover basic concepts in
>   computational and neuronal modeling, information theory and coding,
>   neural networks and learning, neural data analysis and decoding,
>   signal processing and system analysis, statistical learning and
>   probabilistic inference.

(Emphasis mine)